# GTM Custom HTML Tag and Javascript Variables

Tags: javascript, variables, tags, google-tag-manager

I have 2 custom javascript variables (fx_geoLatitude, fx_geoLongitude) that capture latitude and longitude of the user when the page loads on their first session. Firing these variables within a custom HTML tag to populate the console.log is easy enough. I want to populate 2 variables in the data layer with these values, but those variables (latitude, longitude) don't currently exist in our data layer. Is it possible to do this, or do I need to have our dev team update our data layer with these new variables? Also, what would the dataLayer.push in the custom HTML tag look like to do this? Would it be as simple as

```
(function() {
  var latitude={{fx_geoLatitude}};
  var longitude={{fx_geoLongitude}};
  dataLayer.push({
         'latitude' : latitude,
         'longitude' : longitude
  });
})();
```

Comment: Yes, what you have described should do what you want. Have you tried it? What did not work?

Comment: I have confirmed that the 2 javascript functions populate the console.log properly with latitude and longitude. When in preview mode with GTM, these functions show values of undefined when the tag fires.

Comment: Maybe you set the variables after the GTM has initialised. Try to fire your tag on the "DOM Ready" event.